# My while loop is not displaying any outputs after making a search from the arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm able to run it, fill out both Arrays, then input the search criteria but that's it. no results are thrown back.

```
        var SIZE = 4;
        var actors = new Array(SIZE); //array holding actors
        var roles = new Array(SIZE); //array holding roles
        
        
        for (var i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)  {
        
            actors[i] = prompt ("Please enter your "  + (i + 1) + " favorite Actor");
            roles[i] = prompt ("What role did your " + (i + 1)+ " Actor played?");
        }
                    
        var favorite; // hold search actor name
        var found = false;
        var BR = "<br>";    
        
        favorite = prompt ("Please enter the name of your most favorite actor of all");
        
        while (i < size && !(found))    {
            i++;
        
            if (actors[i] == favorite)  {
                found = true;
                document.write("Your favorite actor " + actors[i] + " played the role of " + roles[i] + BR);
                
        /*for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            if ( favorite == actors[i]) {
                found = true;
                document.write("Your favorite actor " + actors[i] + " played the role of " + roles[i] + BR);
        
            }
        
        }
        */
        if (!found) { //if we find nothing 
            document.write("Sorry, we couldn't find an actor with that name" + BR);
        }
```

I have tried using for and also while loop but none work, in my head the while loop makes sense. So im not sure whats the issue.

Comment: `var` doesn't create a local variable to the `for`, the same variable has a value of `SIZE` when the `while` loop starts. But nobody knows what is `size`, it pops out from nowhere, most likely causing an error, which breaks your code. Hit F12 to see the error messages, and stop using `document.write`, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update some parts:

- Please use another variable then `i` in the second loop
- Move increase of counter to the end of scope of the second loop
- Use SIZE in the second loop, as JS is case-sensitive.
  Please check the updated example (https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/xxXxYGB):

```js
var SIZE = 4;
var actors = new Array(SIZE); //array holding actors
var roles = new Array(SIZE); //array holding roles

for (var i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  actors[i] = prompt("Please enter your " + (i + 1) + " favorite Actor");
  roles[i] = prompt("What role did your " + (i + 1) + " Actor played?");
}

var favorite; // hold search actor name
var found = false;
var BR = "<br>";

favorite = prompt("Please enter the name of your most favorite actor of all");
let k = 0
while (k < SIZE && !found) {
  if (actors[k] == favorite) {
    found = true;
    console.log(
      "Your favorite actor " +
        actors[k] +
        " played the role of " +
        roles[k] +
        BR
    );

    if (!found) {
      //if we find nothing
      console.log("Sorry, we couldn't find an actor with that name" + BR);
    }
  }
  k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the problem thanks to @Teemu, a silly mistake I made

had SIZE declared but later down I was using size.